# SQL Server ISDATE before conversion returns error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have been given a task of converting dates on a field that is define as `Varchar(50)`. As expected the dates inside the column were a bit out of the normal formats like this `DECEMBER 11, 2011`

I have used `ISDATE(datefield)` but it says

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

My second option was to update the column using this statement

```
UPDATE dbo.tbl_arrest_information
SET date_arrested = CASE 
                      WHEN ISDATE(date_arrested) > 0 
                         THEN CONVERT(datetime,  date_arrested) 
                         ELSE '01/01/1901' 
                    END
```

I use '01/01/1901' because it doesn't accept null values but it returns an error stating that

> String or binary data would be truncated

I am well aware that the date field has a length of 50 so i am at lost why it is happening.

Any advise would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: if `date_arrested` is a varchar field, then why are you converting to `datetime` while assigning?

Comment: isn't it right to check if it's a valid date before doing anything?what would you suggest?

Comment: try `THEN date_arrested`. And not `THEN CONVERT(datetime,  date_arrested)`

Comment: here is the return message String or binary data would be truncated

Comment: You can check for valid date, what your are missing is, you are converting `varchar` to `datetime` which gives you `xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx` as string output which may not fit into your varchar column, because of limitation that might be specified for the column like `date_arrested varchar(20)`.

Comment: thank you for enlightening actually it is 50 in length when i omitted the convert the same error is returning

Comment: any toughts on skipping null valued field before updating it?i scanned trough the data there are null fields i guess that is where the error is coming from when i try to convert it

Comment: You can check one more `case` as `when date_arrested is null then '01/01/1901'` before checking `ISDATE`

Comment: the trigger on insert update and delete was the one causing the error on the update

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that your date_arrested might be a smalldatetime field which will throw errors that ISDATE() will not find because it assumes you are checking for a datetime field.  You may have to do something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.tbl_arrest_information
SET date_arrested = 
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(date_arrested) > 0 
        THEN CASE WHEN date_arrested BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND '2079-06-05' THEN CONVERT(datetime, date_arrested) ELSE '01/01/1901' END
        ELSE '01/01/1901' END
```

Comment: i will give it a try but base in the result upon querying the data it has something like this type of date OCT 4, 2012 will mssql recognize it?

Comment: date_arrested is a varchar field that is why i sm using isdate() function

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use Correct LANGUAGE And DATEFORMAT With ISDATE()

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;  
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;  
SELECT ISDATE('04/15/2008'); --Returns 1.
```

Returns 1

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;  
SET DATEFORMAT myd;  
SELECT ISDATE('15/04/2008'); --Returns 0.
```

Also USE CONVERT ( 1, 2 ,3 )